# GroupBy and concat array columns pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this data frame

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6]) , (2,[2]),(2,[3])]).toDF(["store", "values"])

+-----+---------+
|store|   values|
+-----+---------+
|    1|[1, 2, 3]|
|    1|[4, 5, 6]|
|    2|      [2]|
|    2|      [3]|
+-----+---------+
```

and I would like to convert into the follwing df:

```
+-----+------------------+
|store|      values      |
+-----+------------------+
|    1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|    2|            [2, 3]|
+-----+------------------+
```

I did this:

```
from  pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy("store").agg(F.collect_list("values"))
```

but the solution has this `WrappedArrays`

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|store|collect_list(values)                          |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
|1    |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]|
|2    |[WrappedArray(2), WrappedArray(3)]            |
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way to transform the `WrappedArrays` into concatenated arrays? Or can I do it differently?

Comment: @desertnaut I post a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426895/counter-function-on-a-arraycolumn-pyspark

Comment: Spark now supports `flatten` function. See Hululu's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354392/5238639

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need a flattening UDF; starting from your own `df`:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def fudf(val):
    return reduce (lambda x, y:x+y, val)

flattenUdf = F.udf(fudf, T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))

df2 = df.groupBy("store").agg(F.collect_list("values"))
df2.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+ 
# |store|                         collect_list(values) | 
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+ 
# |1    |[WrappedArray(1, 2, 3), WrappedArray(4, 5, 6)]| 
# |2    |[WrappedArray(2), WrappedArray(3)]            | 
# +-----+----------------------------------------------+

df3 = df2.select("store", flattenUdf("collect_list(values)").alias("values"))
df3.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+------------------+
# |store|           values |
# +-----+------------------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |2    |[2, 3]            |
# +-----+------------------+
```

**UPDATE** (after comment):

The above snippet will work only with Python 2. With Python 3, you should modify the UDF as follows:

```python
import functools

def fudf(val):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, val)
```

Tested with Spark **2.4.4**.

Comment: This example on pyspark/spark 2.4 fails with the error `NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined`. Do you know why?

Comment: @AlexOrtner it's a Python 3 issue, and not a Spark one; pls see update

Answer (score 24):

For a simple problem like this, you could also use the explode function.  I don't know the performance characteristics versus the selected udf answer though.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6]) , (2,[2]),(2,[3])]).toDF(['store', 'values'])

df2 = df.withColumn('values', F.explode('values'))
# +-----+------+
# |store|values|
# +-----+------+
# |    1|     1|
# |    1|     2|
# |    1|     3|
# |    1|     4|
# |    1|     5|
# |    1|     6|
# |    2|     2|
# |    2|     3|
# +-----+------+

df3 = df2.groupBy('store').agg(F.collect_list('values').alias('values'))
# +-----+------------------+
# |store|           values |
# +-----+------------------+
# |1    |[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]|
# |2    |[2, 3]            |
# +-----+------------------+
```

Note: you could use `F.collect_set()` in the aggregation or `.drop_duplicates()` on df2 to remove duplicate values.

If you want to maintain ordered values in the collected list, I found the following method in another SO answer:

```python
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('store').orderBy('values')
df3 = df2.withColumn('ordered_value_lists', F.collect_list('values').over(w))
# +-----+------+-------------------+
# |store|values|ordered_value_lists|
# +-----+------+-------------------+
# |1    |1     |[1]                |
# |1    |2     |[1, 2]             |
# |1    |3     |[1, 2, 3]          |
# |1    |4     |[1, 2, 3, 4]       |
# |1    |5     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    |
# |1    |6     |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] |
# |2    |2     |[2]                |
# |2    |3     |[2, 3]             |
# +-----+------+-------------------+

df4 = df3.groupBy('store').agg(F.max('ordered_value_lists').alias('values'))
df4.show(truncate=False)
# +-----+------------------+
# |store|values            |
# +-----+------------------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |2    |[2, 3]            |
# +-----+------------------+
```

If the values themselves don't determine the order, you can use `F.posexplode()` and use the `'pos'` column in your window functions instead of `'values'` to determine order.  Note: you will also need a higher level order column to order the original arrays, then use the position in the array to order the elements of the array.

```python
df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3], 1), (1, [4, 5, 6], 2) , (2, [2], 1),(2, [3], 2)]).toDF(['store', 'values', 'array_order'])
# +-----+---------+-----------+
# |store|values   |array_order|
# +-----+---------+-----------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |
# |2    |[2]      |1          |
# |2    |[3]      |2          |
# +-----+---------+-----------+

df2 = df.select('*', F.posexplode('values'))
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+
# |store|values   |array_order|pos|col|
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |0  |1  |
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |1  |2  |
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |2  |3  |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |0  |4  |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |1  |5  |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |2  |6  |
# |2    |[2]      |1          |0  |2  |
# |2    |[3]      |2          |0  |3  |
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+

w = Window.partitionBy('store').orderBy('array_order', 'pos')
df3 = df2.withColumn('ordered_value_lists', F.collect_list('col').over(w))
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+-------------------+
# |store|values   |array_order|pos|col|ordered_value_lists|
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+-------------------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |0  |1  |[1]                |
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |1  |2  |[1, 2]             |
# |1    |[1, 2, 3]|1          |2  |3  |[1, 2, 3]          |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |0  |4  |[1, 2, 3, 4]       |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |1  |5  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    |
# |1    |[4, 5, 6]|2          |2  |6  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] |
# |2    |[2]      |1          |0  |2  |[2]                |
# |2    |[3]      |2          |0  |3  |[2, 3]             |
# +-----+---------+-----------+---+---+-------------------+

df4 = df3.groupBy('store').agg(F.max('ordered_value_lists').alias('values'))
# +-----+------------------+
# |store|values            |
# +-----+------------------+
# |1    |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |2    |[2, 3]            |
# +-----+------------------+
```

Edit:  If you'd like to keep some columns along for the ride and they don't need to be aggregated, you can include them in the `groupBy` or rejoin them after aggregation (examples below).  If they do require aggregation, only group by `'store'` and just add whatever aggregation function you need on the `'other'` column/s to the `.agg()` call.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3], 'a'), (1, [4, 5, 6], 'a') , (2, [2], 'b'), (2, [3], 'b')]).toDF(['store', 'values', 'other'])
# +-----+---------+-----+
# |store|   values|other|
# +-----+---------+-----+
# |    1|[1, 2, 3]|    a|
# |    1|[4, 5, 6]|    a|
# |    2|      [2]|    b|
# |    2|      [3]|    b|
# +-----+---------+-----+

df2 = df.withColumn('values', F.explode('values'))
# +-----+------+-----+
# |store|values|other|
# +-----+------+-----+
# |    1|     1|    a|
# |    1|     2|    a|
# |    1|     3|    a|
# |    1|     4|    a|
# |    1|     5|    a|
# |    1|     6|    a|
# |    2|     2|    b|
# |    2|     3|    b|
# +-----+------+-----+

df3 = df2.groupBy('store', 'other').agg(F.collect_list('values').alias('values'))
# +-----+-----+------------------+
# |store|other|            values|
# +-----+-----+------------------+
# |    1|    a|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |    2|    b|            [2, 3]|
# +-----+-----+------------------+

df4 = (
    df.drop('values')
    .join(
        df2.groupBy('store')
        .agg(F.collect_list('values').alias('values')),
        on=['store'], how='inner'
    )
    .drop_duplicates()
)
# +-----+-----+------------------+
# |store|other|            values|
# +-----+-----+------------------+
# |    1|    a|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
# |    2|    b|            [2, 3]|
# +-----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: How can you keep other columns with this approach?

Comment: You can add them into the groupBy function along with `store`, or you could join the final result with the initial input dataframe on the `store` column.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding them to the groupby.

Answer (score 21):

Now, it is possible to use the flatten function and things become a lot easier.
You just have to flatten the collected array after the groupby.

```
# 1. Create the DF

    df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6]) , (2,[2]),(2,[3])]).toDF(["store","values"])

+-----+---------+
|store|   values|
+-----+---------+
|    1|[1, 2, 3]|
|    1|[4, 5, 6]|
|    2|      [2]|
|    2|      [3]|
+-----+---------+

# 2. Group by store

    df = df.groupBy("store").agg(F.collect_list("values"))

+-----+--------------------+
|store|collect_list(values)|
+-----+--------------------+
|    1|[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5...|
|    2|          [[2], [3]]|
+-----+--------------------+

# 3. finally.... flat the array

    df = df.withColumn("flatten_array", F.flatten("collect_list(values)"))

+-----+--------------------+------------------+
|store|collect_list(values)|     flatten_array|
+-----+--------------------+------------------+
|    1|[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|    2|          [[2], [3]]|            [2, 3]|
+-----+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Nice. Just to add. All these can be done in a single step via `df.groupBy("store").agg(F.flatten(F.collect_list("values")))`

Answer (score 7):

I would probably do it this way.

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [4, 5, 6]) , (2,[2]),(2,[3])]).toDF(["store", "values"])
>>> df.show()
+-----+---------+
|store|   values|
+-----+---------+
|    1|[1, 2, 3]|
|    1|[4, 5, 6]|
|    2|      [2]|
|    2|      [3]|
+-----+---------+

>>> df.rdd.map(lambda r: (r.store, r.values)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).toDF(['store','values']).show()
+-----+------------------+
|store|            values|
+-----+------------------+
|    1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|    2|            [2, 3]|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: How we'll remove duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Since PySpark 2.4, you can use the following code:

```
df = df.groupBy("store").agg(collect_list("values").alias("values"))

df = df.select("store", array_sort(array_distinct(expr("reduce(values, array(), (x,y) -> concat(x, y))"))).alias("values"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined pyspark function to flatten

```
df = df.groupBy("store").agg(f.flatten(f.collect_list("values")).alias("values"))
```

its documentation is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.flatten.html).